# Can two equations simultaneously cancel each other out in a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to write a system of equations in parametric form (which requires all rows but one to be zero'd out). I have managed to manipulate the matrix into:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 & -4\\
2 & -1 & 2 & -4\\
-2 & 1 & -2 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Now operation wise adding row 3 to row 2 would zero it out (or the other way around).

I am wondering if it's permitted to do simultaneous operations to cancel both row 2 and 3 out at the same time to get:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

or would I have to cancel one out and then do more operations to cancel out the other like:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 1 & -2 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}$

and then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are row reducing, there are three operations you can perform: adding a multiple of one row to another, multiplying a row by a non-zero scalar, and swapping two rows. Adding row 3 to row 2 will eliminate row 2, but you cannot simultaneously "zero out" both rows.

In general, when you are trying to get a parametric form for a system, you want to start with an augmented matrix corresponding to the equations, and get the left side of the augmented matrix to [reduced row-echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). You might find the examples [linked here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Interactive_Linear_Algebra_(Margalit_and_Rabinoff)/01%3A_Systems_of_Linear_Equations-_Algebra/1.03%3A_Parametric_Form) to be helpful.